# Track 'conversion' based on callback with Google Experiments

Tags: javascript, google-analytics-api

I'm looking to set up a Google Analytics experiment where we test two pages and tack if a user clicks one of a set of links (don't really care which one of the set).

However, the links will all go off-site and I was hoping to avoid adding a redirect somewhere in between.

What I'd love to do is have a bit of javascript that's called and is counted as a 'conversion' in the experiment, that way I could call it any time one of the buttons is pressed. I don't really care which button, just looking to track the total.

I'm testing this with the following code on two page:

```
<a href="#" onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'User Interaction', 'Click Link']);" class="pal mal h1">Tracked Link</a>
```

This is supposed to correspond to a goal I set up like this:

[image]

So far after three hours (and I've been clicking the link) there are no results howing up in the test.

Comment: What I would love is to have someone pay off my mortgage for me. However, I'm not sure if it's possible. What have you got so far??

Comment: Right now I'm simply looking to see if it's a possibility, The normal experiments I set up are with pre-defined goals and so far from what I've been told I'd need an interstitial page. I'm hoping to avoid that.

Comment: That's where this page comes in handy: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/eventTrackerGuide sounds like it's doable and I can just include that script as part of an event listener through jQuery, or just give each link that event hard-coded (though might not do that).

Comment: Can't you just trigger conversion on click of those links?

Comment: Yes, though I might still do it through a listener so I have a bit more flexibility.